# import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I've created a new project in android studio 3.3.2 it isn't recognizing appCompat and `onCreate` method which comes as default in creation of main activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

should have recognized `onCreate` and **appCompat**

Comment: Is it added: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Answer (score 2):

Goto File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall the whole IDE along with caches

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23809343)

Comment: @ai_learning you are right, my flag has been declined for some reason tho.